# Limit LTspice current for voltage source

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, ltspice, current-limiting

I am trying to simulate a circuit in LTspice but I realized that the USB power supply that I am using has a current limit of 200mA@5V. is there a way tp specify that in LTspice?

I wanted to make the simulation as close to real as possible so I wanted to see if I could limit this since my circuit uses a low quality op-amp and lots of resistors.

Comment: Can't you just simulate it and see if the current goes above 200mA?

Comment: What Kyle said.. as long as the current draw stays below 200 mA, the PSU will look pretty much like a very low impedance voltage source to your circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to limit the current of the voltage source is to use a diode with a current limit `ilimit=200m` and almost no on-resistance and forward voltage:

[image]

Comment: This is, indeed, a solution, but I wouldn't test my luck with 1e15 worth of dynamic range between `Ron` and `Roff` (and zero voltage drop, though this might pass). For a simple showcase it may work, but as soon as you add it in a more complex circuit, you're tempting the Devil. Also, `epsilon` and `revepsilon` are very much your friends.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is a simple current limiter for testing then you can either use the `level=2` VCSW, or the ideal diode, with `ilimit` in the `.model` card:

[image: test]

The diode's limits are only smooth if `epsilon` (or `revepsilon`) are specified, and they provide a simple quadratic smoothing. Otherwise they are hard limits, just like the `level=1` VCSW -- these are not recommended. What I would recommend is the `level=2` VCSW, which has a `tanh()`-based limiting (according to the manual, *LTspice > Circuit Elements > S. ...*):

> Also, the transition of the level 2 switch to current limit is gradual instead of abrupt. At a fixed control voltage, the I-V curve is given by the equation
>
> I(V) = Ilimit * tanh(g(Vc) * V)
>
> where Ilimit defaults to 10 amperes for the level 2 switch.

The testing could have been done with the current source with the `load` flag, but that tends to cause occasional hiccups (not for lack of reasons); hence the behavioural resistor.

Comment: for those wanting some copy pasta: `.model currentLimit D(Ron=1m Vfwd=1m Roff=1meg vrev=1k epsilon=0.1 revepsilon=1 ilimit=200m)`

Answer (score 2):

> I wanted to make the simulation **as close to real as possible**

That will be tricky because it depends on the characteristics of your particular USB power supply.

[lygte-info.dk](https://lygte-info.dk/info/usbPowerSupplyTest%20UK.html) has tested many USB power supplies. Here are a few:-

#6: Rated current 0.5 A. It starts to current limit at ~0.35 A, increasing to 0.5 A at 0 V.

[image]

#9: Rated current 0.75 A. It doesn't have a well defined current limit, and is still putting out over 4.75 V at 1.4 A!

[image]

#11: Rated current 1 A. This one limits sharply at 0.50 A (only half its rating) with a bit of foldback below 2 V.

[image]

Apart from its 'optimistic' rating #11 is probably typical of high current USB supplies, but your 200 mA unit could be quite different. The only way to find out what its current limiting characteristics *really* are is to test it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify what you mean when talking about "USB power supply". The output power of commercial USB power adapters is typically higher than 1W; if you mean the current limit of a bus-powered USB port, USB2 doc states it is one unit (100mA) and can be negotiated via USB protocol to five units (500mA).

If you work with a proprietary product, it is designed most probably around LDO (low dropout) regulator. If this is the case, you can use in your simulation a standard component of LTspice's distribution, like LT3062 for a positive LDO regulator or LT1964 for a negative LDO regulator, these devices output a max current of 200mA @5V, or you can find similar models from a folder .../LTspiceXVII/lib/sym/PowerProducts that approximate your device more accurate. The use of a standard model for current-limiting feature saves you from delving into the depths of USB documentation and still lets "to make the simulation as close to real as possible". No workaround like post-simulation current limiting or "diodes in series" even approximates the current-limiting feature of USB power circuits.

If you have no access to a design of your "USB power supply",  you can test the device in question with tools like those of [TestUSB](http://www.testusb.com/). For example, the page http://www.testusb.com/inrush_issue.htm describes the testing for inrush current of your DUT. This approach is hard way, but it is the only way to reverse-engineer the behavior of a current-limiting feature of your power supply, if you really "want to make the simulation as close to real as possible". The max steady current limit is not the only parameter that matters when you model the USB power supply behavior. To create a trustworthy power-related simulation of USB devices from scratch, you should have a solid knowledge of USB technology https://usb.org/ and DC-DC power conversion techniques.